# Перезапись строки в файле

Tags: c++

Суть данной функции, дописывать в определенную строку вводимые данные. Строка разделена разделителем "=" на две подстроки: первая - это два ключа по-которым и определяется строка, а вторая - текст которого необходимо дописать. У меня возникла проблема с перезаписью, имеется ввиду, что после данной строки всё удаляется. Также, почему-то из `text` записывается только последние слово. Заранее благодарен Вам за помощь и советы.

```
void renamefile(string day,string time,string text)
{
    ifstream fin;
    string line;
    size_t pos;
    fin.open("test1.txt", ifstream::binary);
    ofstream fout("replaced.txt", ofstream::binary);
    if (!fin)
    {
        cout << "Файл не может быть открыт!" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    while (fin.good())
    {
        getline(fin, line);
        pos = line.find(day);

        if (pos != string::npos && line.find(time) != std::string::npos)
        {
            line = line + " " + text;
            fout << line << endl;
            cout << line << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            fout << line << "\n";
        }
    }
    remove("test1.txt");
    rename("replaced.txt", "test1.txt");
    fout.close();
    fin.close();
}
```

Строки в test1.txt

```
1 12:00 = hello 
3 15:40 = what you 
...
```

Comment: И зачем текстовый файл открываете в бинарном режиме?

Comment: И что значит после данной строки все удаляется? И лучше покажите пример строки из файла

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, без бинарного режима у меня  записывает кириллицу.

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, Имеется ввиду, если у меня  строка находится в файле третьей, то при перезаписи, все остальные строки после неё удаляются.  Пример строк из файла , я добавил в коде.

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, в этом и проблема, что я её и не устанавливал.

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, проблему с кириллицей исправил, сделал так, как вы и сказали. А вот с остальными проблемами мне не удаётся решить...

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99766/discussion-between-alex-and-ar-hovsepyan).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

цикл  напишите так:

```
while (getline(fin, line)) {        
    const size_t pos = line.find(day),
                 end = string::npos;
    if ((pos != end) && line.find(time, pos) != end) {  
        line += (" " + text);           
    }
    fout << line << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Проблема с конкатенацией  строк так и осталась(

Comment: а вы выводите на консоль line, убедитесь что нет проблем,  Покажите что вы вывели в файл и что получили

Comment: prntscr.com/php626 prntscr.com/php829

Comment: откуда и как  вы читаете  строку text?

Comment: Если записывать константное значение, то всё нормально.  Данный момент, я просто её ввожу и передаю в функцию.

Comment: значит вводите неправильно. Нужно было в вопросе показывать как вы ее вводите

Comment: http://prntscr.com/phpb8n  Я пробовал и внутри в функции вводить, если проверки на ключи пройдут, но проблема не изменилась

Comment: уберите четвертую строчку_ это повторное обявление size_t pos

Comment: вот смотрите: вы пишете string text; cin >> text;  ,будет введена строка до пробела. Если хотите чтобы прочитались  и пробелы, нужно вводить по другому.  Вводите с помощью getline(cin, text) . Или, чтобы вводить два слова, нужно вводить строку, потом еще одну, и  их сумма будет результатом. Вам нужно было в вопрос включать и программу, чтобы не  разворачивались комментарии.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99788/discussion-between-ar-hovsepyan-and-alex).